# Create an abstract base class for NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, core-data, abstract-class, base-class

I would like create an abstract base class for NSManagedObject which will use by all the entities of my project.

But, when I click on File > New > File NSManagedObject subclass, I can't create one if I don't link it white an entity from my Core Data model.

I would like to know how create an abstract base class for NSManagedObject

Comment: What do you intend for this class to contain and why would it not have an associated entity?

Comment: I would add two virtual pure methods that all my Core Data's entities will implement. So I would like to create an abstract base class for NSManagedObject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a base class, instead, define an @protocol and have each of your managed object subclasses conform to that protocol. By doing this the compiler will verify that they have an implementation of all of the required methods from the protocol.

Comment: Yes, you're right ! Your solution looks better than create an abstract base class for my entites

Comment: After thinking, I need a method in all my entity classes but with no need to be overwritten. So basically, an abstract class could be the good solution.

Comment: Consider also a category on `NSManagedObject`. Be careful with naming, but it will add the method to all instances. Look also at mogenerator and see if it can help (it can) with your overall approach.

Comment: Thanks you again for your perfect answer. :) I will use mogenerator

Comment: An [informal protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Protocol.html) may be a better fit for your needs.

Comment: you can have a protocol and refer to the subclasses collectively as id<protocol> but you still need a base class for the abstract method implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Paul Goracke went into this in depth in a talk a couple of months ago. His blog post is at http://corporationunknown.com/blog/2014/02/16/core-data-potpourri/. Slides are at http://xcoders.s3.amazonaws.com/2014-02-13%20Core%20Data%20Potpourri.pdf, and a video of the talk is at http://vimeo.com/89370886.

I'm a long-time MOGenerator user and fan. Paul's approach to NSMO base class, though, provides almost all of the features that draw me to MOGenerator.